# Retrieving objects from parse into table view cell

Tags: ios, parse-platform, tableview

I have created an object and saved it to the backend named NewCar and there are 4 strings attached to which are year, make, model, horsepower I'm having troubles pulling the data from parse and placing it into my table here is a few pieces of my code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"NewCar"];
    [query whereKey:@"year" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {

        } else {
            self.cars = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.cars count];
}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"garageCell";
    garageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[garageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.usernameDisplay.text = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"];

    //I need to display the year, make and model below here.

    cell.carYearLabel.text = [[PFObject objectWithClassName:@"NewCar"] objectForKey:@"year"];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 236;
}
```

I am able to display the username in my custom cell, but can't figure out how to display the year, make and model values. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have been looking through the documentation in Parse and can't seem to figure it out just in case you are wondering if I tried there.

I also want to add in the code where I added the object to Parse this might help in figuring this out as well.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    NSString *year = self.carYear.text;
    NSString *make = self.carMake.text;
    NSString *model = self.carModel.text;
    NSString *horsepower = self.carHorsepower.text;

    if ([year length] == 0 || [make length] == 0 || [model length] == 0 || [horsepower length] == 0) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"You might have missed a field" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alertView show];
    } else {

        PFObject *newCar = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"NewCar"];
        newCar[@"year"] = year;
        newCar[@"make"] = make;
        newCar[@"model"] = model;
        newCar[@"horsepower"] = horsepower;
        [newCar saveInBackground];

        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
}
```

Comment: What result doest that code give you? Is your carYearLabel empty? If you log [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"NewCar"] and [[PFObject objectWithClassName:@"NewCar"] objectForKey:@"year"], what do they give you?

Comment: I'm trying to do an NSLog, but all it says is query with some numbers after it.

Comment: Well that means it exists anyway. How about the log of [[PFObject objectWithClassName:@"NewCar"] objectForKey:@"year"]? What does it give you?

Comment: @rdelmar it just says null. I added the code where I save the object above.

Comment: self.cars should be used to access your object now. Try to log self.cars and see what you get.

Comment: @rahimjan okay now we are getting somewhere, I'm still fairly new to ios programming, but the nslog gave me this "<NewCar:eczg5Vm07u:(null)> {\n    horsepower = 450;\n    make = Nissan;\n    model = GTR;\n    year = 2014;\n}"

Comment: PFObject *year = [self.cars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.carYearLabel.text = [year objectForKey:@"year"]; @rahimjan thank you for helping me out I just figured out how to display the items, such an easy mistake thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so instead of using

```
cell.carYearLabel.text = [[PFObject objectWithClassName:@"NewCar"] objectForKey:@"year"];
```

You can use the following

```
cell.carYearLabel.text = [self.cars objectForKey:@"NewCar"] valueForKey:@"year"];
```